# How to adding ACF fields to a taxonomy term foreach loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

Hi WordPress nerds out there, 
I need help with this loop, I want to display an image that I have added with advanced custom field plugin but it seems to not work in this case. I know something is missing from my code, but I can't find the solution. Here is the reference article that I used in the implementation. [link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)

[image]

```
<?php
    // get the current taxonomy term
    $term = get_queried_object();

    // vars
    $image = get_field('category_featured_image', $term);
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

    

    foreach ( get_categories( [ 
    'orderby'=> 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'exclude' => array(1)
    ] ) as $category ) { 
    
    if( $image ) : 
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size, "", ["class" => "category-feature-image"] );
    endif; ?>

    <h2 class="category-snippet__title"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
    <p class="category-snippet__description"><?php echo $category->description; ?></p>
    <a class="category-snippet" href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Learn more', 'pluto'); ?>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($image);` output?

Comment: Well, that's why. The `get_field()` function isn't returning an image. It's `NULL`. Hence `$image = NULL`. So, assuming that `$term` is an actual object (might want to double check with `var_dump($term);`) then make sure that `category_featured_image` is a valid key so check that too.

Comment: I have confirmed `category_featured_image` is the key, and Return Format is Image ID. Here is the article from AFC https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/ That I used in reference

Comment: Did you check that `$term` is an actual object as well?

Comment: `WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 58
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2023-02-02 12:12:04
    [post_title] => Our Work
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_name] => our-work
    [post_modified] => 2023-02-02 12:12:04
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2023-02-02 12:12:04
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => http://neiked.local/?page_id=58
    [post_type] => page
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251596/discussion-between-stiviniii-and-cabrerahector).

Comment: That's the problem then. You're expecting `get_queried_object();` to return a category object when in reality it's returning a post object. That's why when you try to use `$term` with `get_field()` it returns NULL, your post doesn't have a field called `category_featured_image`.

Comment: Can this issue be resolved by modifying CPT or what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is the code bellow after some research I discovered, `$term = get_queried_object();` On any singular page (a single post, a single page, or a post in a custom post type), it will return the WP_Post object of that post or page.

```
<?php   
        foreach ( get_categories( [ 
        'orderby'=> 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'exclude' => array(1)
        ] ) as $category ) : 

            $image = get_field('category_featured_image', $category);
            $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size

            $term_link = get_term_link( $category, 'category' );
        
            if( $image ) : 
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size, "", ["class" => "category-feature-image"] );
            endif; ?>

            <h2 class="category-snippet__title"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
            <p class="category-snippet__description"><?php echo $category->description; ?></p>
            <a class="category-snippet" href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Learn more', 'pluto'); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```